# Начало изучения ЯП java

Tags: ide, java

Решил взяться за изучение данного ЯП.

Как я понял, на данный момент актуальная версия Java SE 7. Но там вроде еще есть классификация платформ Java, так что это? Какую выбрать?

И да, какую среду под 7-ку лучше??

Можно ли в [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) сделать настройки под Java SE 7 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как я понял, на данный момент актуальная версия Java SE 7. Но там вроде еще есть классификация платформ Java, так что это? Какую выбрать?

7ку мало кто использует. Ждут пока пофиксят баги. Лучше использовать старую проверенную 1.6 (хотя это не столь уж и важно).

> И да, какую среду под 7-ку лучше??

Можете пользоваться JDK/JRE 1.6 (runtime) + Eclipse / Netbeans / Idea (IDE).

> Можно ли в sublime test 2 сделать настройки под java SE 7 ?

Не в курсе.

Answer (score 3):

Когда я писал на Java, мне понравилась среда разработки [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/)

Answer (score 3):

По-мне 7 версия вполне работоспособная, не замечал никаких глюков, хотя это может от   специфики зависит...
IDE использую IDEA(Community Edition) для моих целей её хватает с головой, вообще IDEA   очень хорошая, как и ко всему хорошему - к ней быстро привыкаешь =).
Так же може использовать Netbeans и Eclipse, выбор IDE - дело вкуса.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

зашел туда, а там java, javaFX, Java EE... немного растерялся) Чт за они?

Comment: не обращайте внимания, вам надо java / java se / j2se

Answer (score 1):

Из IDE - NetBeans... А так лучше с Notepad++ или Far (есть встроенный редактор, хорошо-бы еще плагин подсветки синтаксиса установить (Far Colorer)) начинать... Принципы функционирования быстрее поймете, а там дальше и на IDE перейдете. :)